# How do you compare two things in Newspeak?

Tags: 1984, george-orwell

Let's say one thing is good, but the other thing is better. In Newspeak they would be would be "good" and "doubleplusgood".

So how do you compare two things in Newspeak?

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question?

Comment: That's pretty much it.  The concept of the language wasn't new words, but to limit thought, because the words didn't carry enough meaning behind them.  *Better* was a general concept that could be applied to any quality - *doubleplusgood* was a specific concept that meant better for the party.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're almost there. "*I like A better than B*" would become "*A is good, B is plusgood*", leaving room for a third item that is "*doubleplusgood*".

> *Or again, if you want a stronger version of "good", what sense is
> there in having a whole string of vague useless words like "excellent"
> and "splendid" and all the rest of them? **"Plusgood" covers the
> meaning, or " doubleplusgood" if you want something stronger still.***
> ...
> ***In the end the whole notion of goodness and badness will be covered by only six words — in reality, only one word***
>
> <sup><sub>1984 - Chapter One.</sub></sup>

Comment: Plusgood answer. Plus one.

Comment: by demonstrating preference, you have shown individualism. This is ungood as there is only the party

Comment: @Naib - If the Party says A is good, goodthink says A is good. To say A is ungood is thoughtcrime. Crimestop or thinkpol will come.

Comment: we have always considered B to be plusgood. the party expects doublethink

Comment: @Naib - B is good. A is ungood. Minitruth will correct misprint,